# in angularjs, how do I access a formController?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

when reseting the data in a form, wish to set `form.setPristine()`, but the `formController` is not yet registered in $scope.

this may seem like a dumb question, but how can I find the `formController`?

in the code below, get "TypeError: Cannot call method 'setPristine' of undefined"

#### index.html

```
<ng-form name='wordForm' ng-controller='wordCntl' >
  ...
</ng-form>
```

#### word.js

```
var langMod = angular.module('langMod', []);

langMod.controller( 'wordCntl', function($scope,$http,$location) {

  // data
  $scope.dflt = { wrd_id: '', usr_id: '', ln: '', word: '' };
  $scope.orig = {};
  $scope.data = {};

  // pull record default
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.orig = angular.copy($scope.dflt);
    $scope.data = angular.copy($scope.orig);
    $scope.wordForm.setPristine();
  }

  $scope.reset();
};
```

the only way I know to get to the `formController` is when it's been set in the `$scope`.  but it's not there yet, and I do not know how to find it.

Comment: Why don't you just check for `$scope.wordForm` for undefined\null before calling this method. If the form is not there once its loaded it would be in pristine state already.

Comment: @Chandermani - true, but what if I wanted to set the form dirty?

Comment: You can create a watch on wordForm and when it gets assigned the first time you can do whatever you want.

Comment: It is `$setPristine()` not `setPristine()`.

Answer (score 2):

Directive controllers are shared among other directives. To access it, create a custom directive on the form and it becomes the 4th property to the link function.

Inside your custom directive you do this:

```
//inside custom directive
link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
  controller.$setPristine();
}
```

I realize this is a very literal answer to your question. The real solution is probably not to call $scope.reset yet... why would you need to? Doesn't your form start off pristine anyway? If not, what is making it not pristine?

Comment: an answer to your question, am using the `reset()` function both to initialize the data and as the `onclick` trigger to the reset button in the form.  so yes, I could use a directive on the `onclick` which would both call `reset()` and `setPristine()`

Comment: thanks! your answer makes perfect sense, but is there another way to get to the `formController` without having to use a directive?  or are we guaranteed that whenever we wish to use a `formController` that a `directive` would be appropriate?  what if, for example, I wished to start off with a `dirty` form for some reason?

Comment: cannot make that work!!  the `controller` parameter is `undefined`

Comment: The directive must live on the same element for the controller to be shared. The simplest solution for this is to not call $scope.wordForm.setPristine() initially. You can do it in subsequent calls to reset. Do this by checking for its existence in your reset function... as the form will start of pristine anyway, it should be fine. Your data will be set up and the form starts off pristine.